# Color of a tabular cell determined by cell content

Tags: colortbl

I am using the `colortbl` package to color the cells of a table. I want to be able to color a cell depending on the value in the cell. In my specific case, I'd like to enter a number between 30 & 90 and color the cell in a shade of gray. I used the `fp` package to create a command that displays the value of the argument in a colored cell as shown in the MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{fp}

\newcommand{\colorcell}[1]{%
\FPeval{grayshade}{1.171-0.00857*#1}%
\cellcolor[gray]{\grayshade}#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\cellcolor[gray]{.4}85 & \cellcolor[gray]{.8}85\\
\colorcell{73} & 0
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

However, this gives me an error that `\grayshade` is an undefined control sequence. I can rewrite the code to know that `\grayshade` is defined; it seems that `colortbl` isn't liking it for some reason.

How can I fix my code to make this work?

A solution probably exists using things like `pgf`/`Tikz`, and I am open to these, but I'd also like to see how this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of `\grayshade` is not expanded when passed to `\cellcolor` and is not longer available when the cell colour is applied. To ensure its availability, we can create a global, expanded definition `\xdef\tempa{\grayshade}` to hold the value calculated by FP.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{fp}

\newcommand{\colorcell}[1]{%
  \FPeval{\grayshade}{1.171-0.00857*#1}%
  \xdef\tempa{\grayshade}%
  \cellcolor[gray]{\tempa}#1%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\cellcolor[gray]{.4}85 & \cellcolor[gray]{.8}85\\
\colorcell{73} & 0
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: 4 shades of grey]

Answer (score 3):

The `\cellcolor` macro doesn't expand its colour argument. Below I've expanded it using `\edef\x{\noexpand\cellcolor...}\x` in order to guarantee that `\graycolor` is expanded to the value calculated by `\FPeval`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\newcommand{\colorcell}[1]{%
  \FPeval\grayshade{1.171-0.00857*#1}%
  \edef\x{\noexpand\cellcolor[gray]{\grayshade}}\x #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
  \cellcolor[gray]{.4}85 & \cellcolor[gray]{.8}85 \\
  \colorcell{73} & 0
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```